# Set background color in table cell

Tags: jquery, html

I am exploring HTML and Jquery, I have a simple page in which i am using table with one table row and ten table cells. Background color of each cell is Yellow when page loads.
 I need to change the color of each cell in every two seconds. So, what i need to accomplish is, get each cell id and periodically change cell color one after another.
 For example first change back-ground color
(to green) of cell whose id is one, than wait for two second move to next cell id which is 2 change it's back-ground color do this upto cell id 10.

```
 $('table #my_table td').each(function(){
 var ids = $(this).attr('id');
 console.log(ids);// This will return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
 });

 <div>
    <table id="my_table" style="width:55%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                    <td id="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="2" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="4" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="5" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="6" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="7" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="8" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="9" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id="10" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: $('table #my_table td').css("background","#FF0000")?

Comment: Use an [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or chained [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to perform an action every X seconds. If you want more specific help, please post your attempt to solve this yourself so we can help you to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to assign `id` to each table row. Just simply handle each row by looping them by using `setInterval()` is fine. Like this:

```js
$('table#my_table tr').each(function() {
  var tr = $(this);
  setInterval(function() {
    var current = tr.attr('data-current');
    tr.find('td').eq(current).css('background-color', tr.data('color'));
    current++;
    tr.attr('data-current', current);
    if (current > tr.find('td').length) {
      tr.find('td').css('background-color', '#fff');
      tr.attr('data-current', 0);
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table" style="width:55%">
  <tbody>
    <tr data-color="#ff0" data-current="0">
      <td id="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="2" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="4" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="5" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="6" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="7" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="8" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="9" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="10" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-color="#f00" data-current="0">
      <td id="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="2" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="3" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="4" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="5" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="6" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="7" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="8" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="9" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="10" style="border: 1px solid black;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: no idea who give you minus point but i have shared html code as well but your code changes all cells color together

Comment: I've updated my answer with your html markup and edited a little javascript.

Comment: one last thing how to set white color if last cell color is changed to yellow?
Again set all cell colors to white and than yellow afterwards. and alos can we do this on TD/ TR level i have many rows in tables i want different colors for different row td.

Comment: Updated again the html markup and script. Please see if it's what you need, (I changed the timer to 200ms for testing)

Comment: impressive solution  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var td = 0;
var itv = setInterval(function() {

  $('table#my_table tr').eq(td).css('background-color', '#ff0');
   clearColour(td);
  td++;

  if (td === $('table#my_table td').length) {
  
    clearInterval(itv);
    $('table#my_table tr').eq(td).css('background-color', '#ff0');
  }
  
}, 2000);



function clearColour(td){
$('table#my_table tr').eq(--td).css('background-color', 'white');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Testing 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Testing 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Testing 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Testing 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yellow color should remain until all cell becomes yellow once all TD are yellow than make all white and restart the color changing process.
It would be great if we can do it with row level ID it gives me more control if i want different colors for different row cells.

Comment: Please note that your answer was copied from my answer. (My answer has already been updated now.)